# Three golden calfs

Tags: commentaries, melachim-kings-book-of, parashat-ki-tisa

What are the similarities and differences between the story of the egel hazahav (golden calf) ([Ki Sisa chapter 32](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893)) and the story of the two golden calves made by Jeroboam ([I Melachim 12:28](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15896#v=28&showrashi=true))?

Comment: And the 14 golden lions of Salomon

Comment: @AlBerko Lions != cows

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that Bnai Yisrael as a mob, forced Aharon to build the egel in order to replace Moshe Rabbeinu when they panicked after (they thought) he was late returning from Har Sinai.

[Ki Sisa 32:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893#v=1)

> When the people saw that Moses was late in coming down from the
>   mountain, the people gathered against Aaron, and they said to him:
>   "Come on! Make us gods that will go before us, because this man Moses,
>   who brought us up from the land of Egypt we don't know what has become
>   of him."

As soon as Moshe returned, the people abandoned all thought of the idol. Only three thousand out of the 600,000 actually deserved the full punishment as we see in [Ki Sisa 32:28](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893#showrashi=true&v=28)

> The sons of Levi did according to Moses' word; on that day some three
>   thousand men fell from among the people.

On the other hand Yerav'am built the idols with malice aforethought in order to prevent the people from returning to the temple. He built one at each border (north and south) in order to make sure that they would find it easier to perform the worship that he made up. He also created a new *festival* in the month after Succos in order to make sure that they would not continue going to Yerushalayim.

[I Melachim 12:28-33](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15896#v=28&showrashi=true)

> 28 The king took counsel and made two golden calves, and he said to
>   them, saying, "It is far for you to go up to Jerusalem; here are your
>   gods, O Israel, that have brought you up from the land of Egypt."
>
> 33 And he brought up offerings on the altar which he has made in Beth
>   El on the fifteenth day of the eighth month, in the month that he had
>   fabricated from his heart, and he made a festival for the children of
>   Israel, and he went up to the altar to burn the incense.